# How to implement subplots (several blochsphere plots) using qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, bloch-sphere, matrix-representation

Qiskit seems to use matplotlib for rendering bloch spheres under the hood. Therefore, it would be nice if we could also make use of matplotlib's subplot technique.

I would like to implement subplots, each containing a bloch sphere (with different vectors), like the plot matrix in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/eventplot_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-eventplot-demo-py). I would be very grateful for a short help.

The result should look something like this at the end of the day:

[image]

Comment: Qiskit's visualization methods like plot_bloch_vector return a matplotlib figure instance. For example: fig = plt.figure(plot_bloch_vector([0,1,0])). Did you try to plot multiple figures like this?

Comment: It sounds to be a good idea. I didn't tired that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `plot_bloch_vector` accepts `matplotlib.axes.Axes` to use for rendering the bloch sphere. So, you can create a `figure`, add a new `Axes` for each bloch sphere, then pass it to `plot_bloch_vector`:

```
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_vector
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize = [6, 9])

states = [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0.6, 0.8, 0],
    [0.6, 0, 0.8],
    [0, 0.6, 0.8],
]

# Values are in fractions of figure width and height:
positions = [
    [0, 0],
    [0.5, 0],
    [0, 0.333],
    [0.5, 0.333],
    [0, 0.667],
    [0.5, 0.667],
]

for m in range(len(states)):
    ax = fig.add_axes([positions[m][0], positions[m][1], 0.5, 0.333], axes_class = Axes3D)
    plot_bloch_vector(states[m], ax = ax)
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It even allows me to use the well-known `axes` methods from matplotlib. Thank you!